# Android: Find specific character in String

Tags: java, android, string, character, indexof

I have a string that contains many asterisk' '*'. I want to be able to search through the entire string and swap the asterisks for another character or String.

SOLVED:
            String name = getString(string[i]);
            String newName;

```
            CharSequence orig = "****"; 
            CharSequence replaced = "Frank";

            newName = name.replace(orig, replaced);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use replace, or replaceAll.  Link to relevant doc below:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29

For your problem, the answer would be

```
getString = getString.replace('*', 'x');
```

'x' being the character to replace '*' with.

Comment: Thanks @karl_. I have just solved it seconds before you posted but i'm sure this will help many people in the future also!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) as suggested.

But in the way you started it would be:

```
String name = getString(text[obNum]);

for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
    if(name[i] == '*') {
        name[i] = 'x';
    }
}
```